# How to ensure the response for image is complete?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, web-scraping, captcha

I'm doing a webscraping project in ASP.net for a website, as there is a need for Catpcha code, hence I need to get the Captcha code for users to key in before continue.

So far the project is working fine, but the only problem I found is that sometimes the captcha code response was not entirely captured hence converting the response stream to Image caused the following errors:
"Parameter is invalid."

I noticed that web browsers do not have this problem, and it always can show the captcha code nicely as long as the server is not down.

However, this doesn't make sense to HttpWebRequest, it is sometimes able to get it, and sometimes not, may I know is there a way to ensure that the Response Stream is complete?

My Code snippet is as follow:

```
public Image GetCaptchaCode()
{
    Image returnVal = null;
    Uri uri = new Uri(URL_CAPTCHA);
    HttpWebRequest request = null;
    HttpWebResponse response = null;

    try
    {
        // Get Cookies
        CookieCollection cookies = this.GetCookies();
        foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cookie.Name + ": " + cookie.Value);
        }

        // Get Catpcha
        request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get; // use GET for loading Captcha
        request.CookieContainer = this._cookies; // Store Cookies Info
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        // Add more cookies
        if (cookies != null)
        {
            request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
        }

        // Handle Gzip Compression
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, HEADER_TYPE);
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        request.Referer = URL_REFERER;
        request.UserAgent = USER_AGENT;

        // Get Response
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        returnVal = Image.FromStream(response.GetResponseStream());

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errMsg = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (uri != null) uri = null;
        if (request != null) request = null;

        if (response != null)
        {
            response.Close();
            response = null;
        }

    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: how are you getting this "parameter is invalid"?  Is this part of exception?  If so, provide all the details and the line at which it happens.

Comment: What is the HttpWebResponse.StatusCode before the call to GetResponseStream?

Comment: Dear all Gurus, I managed to get the ideas as the web server will have some authentication, hence getting the captcha will have a few redirects, and "CookieCollection cookies = this.GetCookies();" refrain it from redirects hence the asp.net session id is not found. anyway, thanks for all the helps, fiddlers 2 is a real good tool for webscraping. thanks!